# how to mock response of async call inside sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a code that looks like this:

```
export function* terminateOrderSaga(action: Action) {
            const {orderId, onPaymentRequired} = action.payload;
            const {
                data: {unsubscribe: unsubscribeResponse},
            } = yield call(unsubscribeMutation, {
                orderId,
            });
    
            const {status, ticketInfo} = unsubscribeResponse || {};
            const {zones, price} = ticketInfo;
}
```

I would like to mock this request:

```
yield call(unsubscribeMutation, {
   orderId,
});
```

I tried few options in test file like:

```
unsubscribeMutation.mockImplementationOnce({unsubscribe: {status: "OK", ticketInfo:{price:23, zones: 'ASD'}})
```

but id does not seem to work, it seems like it is still doing a call to server and not returning the mock response!

Comment: `mockImplementationOnce` expects a _function_. Perhaps try with `mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ unsubscribe: {status: "OK", ticketInfo:{price:23, zones: 'ASD'}))` or use `mockReturnValueOnce`.